# Crash with error EXC_bad_access code=1 address=0x0

Tags: c++, for-loop, crash

I've searched this website and many others for this seemingly common crash people experience and I've read that this error means that a line in my code is trying to access *deallocated memory*.

I'm a beginner in this language and am trying to play around with arrays in order to fully understand them and I can't seem to figure out what my error is.

I will try to make it as easy and clear as possible: My program simply asks for :

1. How many subjects and -subsequently- grades the user is going to input
2. The name of the subject followed by its grade for the number previously entered by the user (So if user entered **3** at the first question the program is going to ask **three** times to input the subject and grade)

My code is the following :

```
void moyenne()
{
string subjects[0];
double grade[0];
int lim;

cout << "**Program which calculates the average grade of several subjects, each with coefficient 1 **\n";
cout << "How many subjects are you going to enter grades for?\n";

cin >> lim; // User enters the "limit" to which the "for" loop is going to end

cout << "Please enter seperately the subjects of the grades you'd like to enter followed with their respectful grade.\n";

for (int i = 0; i<=lim-1; i++) // "lim-1" because if lim = x, i will go from 0 to x which is x+1 array slots
{
    cout << "Enter subject.\n";
    cin >> subjects[i];
    cout << "Enter grade for " << subjects[i] << ".\n";
    cin >> grade[i];
}

for (int j = 0; j<=lim-1; j++)
{
    cout << subjects[j] << grade[j];
}
}
```

The program systematically and precisely crashes at the third request for a **grade**, whatever `lim`the user inputs as long as `lim > 2`. The error is : [image: Error screenshot]

And the console is :

`**Program which calculates the average grade of several subjects, each with coefficient 1 **
How many subjects are you going to enter grades for?
3
Please enter seperately the subjects of the grades you'd like to enter followed with their respectful grade.
Enter subject.
Maths
Enter grade for Maths.
15
Enter subject.
Physics
Enter grade for Physics.
17
Enter subject.
English
(lldb)`

Comment: Even if `string subjects[0];` is legal (I couldn't be bothered checking), think about what that means - you are allocating space for absolutely *zero* array elements. Hence, when you try to use the first one, `subjects[0]`, what do you think should happen? Don't be one of those half-breed C+ developers, embrace C++ and use vectors. Or, if you *must* be a C+ coder, at least create the arrays after the size is known (and use the size, not zero).

Comment: I wouldn't call myself a developper I have for sole intention of understanding the language for now. Ok so I was wrong, I declared my array with an allocated space of 0 because I though I could simply declare it like I do with integers and strings (not give them a value and decide later on). So I am not allowed to do that with arrays, is there another way to decide later on the size of an array or do I *need* to use vectors as you say?

Comment: Arrays are fixed in size. Once you make them, you can't make them bigger. Best you can do is go with pointers and dynamic memory and make a `new`, larger, array copy the old into the new, `delete[]` the old and repoint at the new. Pain in the butt. `vector` does all this crap, and more, for you.